# Timezones when working with VEMCO VR2AR acoustic telemetry data

Tags: r, telemetry, acoustic-telemetry

I'm wondering what the typical procedure for working with timezones for acoustic telemetry data is (part of a GLATOS array). If VR2AR receivers were initialized correctly to our PC clock and the time differences were correct to our actual timezone (in this case Eastern/US) and UTC is the default programming for the receivers, I assume our detections come out as UTC.

So, when I download and go to start analyzing, do I need to specify when using as.POSIX() in R that tz = Eastern/US? Does it matter? I tried changing my detection timestamps from UTC to US/Eastern and the timestamps didn't change.

Thanks for helping out a newbie! :)

Comment: Does [tz argument in as.POSIXct] matter? Yes. Internally POSIXct objects are all in UTC and the tz arg tells as.POSIXct how to convert from tz to UTC.

Comment: So if your data file contains timestamps are in UTC (typical of CSV files written by Innovasea's VUE; but do verify if that's what you are using), then you should set tz = "UTC" in as.POSIXct.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was getting hung up on why we set the tz as UTC first, and then do the conversion to the desired tz following.  So, ultimately, I should be converting to my 'desired' tz before conducting any analyses/ creating figures correct?

Comment: All POSIXct objects have an internal value in UTC (elapsed seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) and a "tzone" attribute that determines the time zone when displayed/printed/written. So if you have a timestamp in a text file that's in UTC, you should read that into R then set 'tz = "UTC"' in as.POSIXct to ensure that the internal value is correct. If, for convenience, you want to see the data in another time zone (e.g., "US/Eastern"), then change/set the "tzone" attribute to the desired time zone (eg, using base attr() or lubridate::with_tz(). Doing so does not change the internal value...

Comment: ... so setting the tzone attribute doesn't affect computations, but beware that it does affect the way timestamps are written to disk. So, for example, "2022-05-17 17:09:32 UTC"  "2022-05-17 13:09:32 US/Eastern" are numerically equivalent (1652807373) but would be written to a CSV file differently: "2022-05-17 17:09:32" and  "2022-05-17 13:09:32". Ambiguity can be an issue since the tzone is enforced when writing, but the time zone itself is not written (for many write functions). Common methods to ensure proper tzone after writing are to use metadata file and/or include tzone in column names.

Answer (score 0):

Without the relevant lines of code, I can only guess you might be missing a step in converting the TZ, i.e., you may be assigning different TZs rather than converting between them.

If this is indeed the case,  you can first use `lubridate::force_tz` to define the current TZ. Then use `lubridate::with_tz` to convert it to the desired TZ.

Here's an example, though I didn't quite understand what TZ within Eastern/US you're aiming for.

datetime as character:

```
dt = c("2019-06-25 14:15:47 UTC","2019-06-25 22:10:17 UTC", "2019-06-25 23:20:57 UTC", "2019-07-25 21:18:01 UTC", "2019-07-25 21:18:42 UTC", "2019-07-25 21:20:11 UTC")
```

define as POSIXct:

```
dt_pos = as.POSIXct(dt, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

assign *current* TZ (UTC\GMT in this example):

```
dt_gmt = force_tz(dt_pos, tzone = "GMT")
```

convert to desired TZ (New York, US):

```
dt_NY = with_tz(dt_gmt, tzone = "America/New_York")
```

compare outputs:

> dt_gmt

[1] "2019-06-25 14:15:47 GMT" "2019-06-25 22:10:17 GMT" "2019-06-25 23:20:57 GMT" "2019-07-25 21:18:01 GMT" "2019-07-25 21:18:42 GMT" "2019-07-25 21:20:11 GMT"

> dt_NY

1] "2019-06-25 10:15:47 EDT" "2019-06-25 18:10:17 EDT" "2019-06-25 19:20:57 EDT" "2019-07-25 17:18:01 EDT" "2019-07-25 17:18:42 EDT" "2019-07-25 17:20:11 EDT"

Comment: Great thank you so much! I think I was getting hung up on why we set the tz as UTC first, and then do the conversion to the desired tz following. Thank you!